# Ionic - Issue in displaying more than one page of PDF using pdfmake

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I am developing an Ionic application in which I have generated the PDF using `pdfmake`.

But, I could not able to display the pdf **if it is more than one page** as the `pageBreak` property does not work

**Document definition object :**

```
var documentdefinition = {
 content: [
           {
           text: 'Unordered list',
           style: 'header'
           },
           {
           ol: [
                'item 1',
                'item 2',
                'item 3',
                ]
           },
           {
           text: '\n\nUnordered list with longer lines',
           style: 'header',
           pageBreak: 'before',
           pageOrientation: 'landscape'
           },
           {
           ol: [
                'item 1',
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ..',
                'item 3',
                ]
           },
           {
           text: '\n\nNested lists',
           style: 'header',
           pageBreak: 'before',
           pageOrientation: 'portrait'
           },
           {
           ol: [
                'item 1',
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ..',
                {
                ol: [
                     'subitem 1',
                     'subitem 2',
                     'subitem 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...',
                     'subitem 4',
                     'subitem 5',
                     ]
                },
                'item 3\nsecond line of item3',
                ]
           },
           ],
 styles: {
 header: {
 bold: true,
 fontSize: 15
 }
 },
 defaultStyle: {
 fontSize: 12,
 }
 };
```

As the result of the above document definition ,only the following content is displayed

**Unordered list**

1.item 1 
 2.item 2 
 3. item 3

Please help me finding the solution.

Comment: It's not clear how you display the PDF created: `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();` or `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('file.pdf');` and then   open manually PDF file?

Comment: I have created the pdf 'pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition)' . I just followed the same way mentioned http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-create-and-display-a-pdf-file-in-your-ionic-app/

Comment: You question was incomplete. However, the pdfMake library create a right document containing 3 pages (with pagebreaks). Probably the issue is on another part of the code presented in that article.